# The PHP script i'm using Is creating processes but not stopping them, how can I solve this?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this script in WordPress, But every time it runs it leaves it's process running.

What can I do to end the process when it's done?

```
<?php
add_action('init', function(){
  if(empty($_REQUEST['user_role_via_js']))
    return; // Not applicable.

  //$user      = new WP_User((integer)$_REQUEST['user_role_via_js']); // Acquire user based on input ID.
$user = new WP_User(0, (string)$_REQUEST['user_role_via_js']); // Based on a username.

  $role       = reset($user->roles); // Get the role for this user.

  header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Output JSON response.
  exit(json_encode(compact('role')));
});
```

Comment: you may want to take a look at what `exit()` does.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work, the process is left even though this script has 'exit()' That's why I don't understand what could be the problem

Comment: you might try to replace your `exit()` statement with a simple `print`or `echo`. a PHP script should clean up behind itself once it is finished. And yes... exit should do that, too, but i guess it might not do that for your case because it is called inside a callback. That is just a guess, though.

Comment: i'd remove the `json_encode(...)` to the line above, maybe `exit()` is exiting to soon, that's just a guess...use `register_shutdown_function()` to run code after `exit()` has been called, to debug more

Comment: maybe you can explain what you mean by process running?

Comment: @gwillie I didn't understand what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: @David This script is causing a PHP process to run on the server with high CPU and a lot of memory, so I want to close it after it runs.

Comment: no its not the code above, when its finshed, the only memory you have is the wp user, the mysql connection is always active so its not that either. The process is definitely finished after exit. Unless you have hit a unknown bug which i doubt. if you remove the function, how is the cpu usage improved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help.

```
echo json_encode( compact('role') );

exit(); // not really required at end of script
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try today